# MapR Sandbox Hive, connect with eclipse JAVA JDBC

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, hive, mapr

I downloaded MapR-Sandbox-For-Hadoop-vmware and run it successfully, however, I want to access the Hive database via JDBC Java code from eclipse, how can I do that? 
Currently, I can access MapR Sandbox Hive from the following interface: http://192.168.206.130:8888/beeswax/#query on my windows.

Comment: If someone has/know a detailed explanation of this process, please share me, otherwise, do not share links from MapR website because I failed to configure them

Comment: Maybe you should post what you've tried so far